# Why is VmallocTotal 34359738367 kB?

Tags: proc, meminfo

`/proc/meminfo` has a memory statistic `VmallocTotal`. It is described as

> Total size of vmalloc memory area.

in [proc's man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

and elsewhere as

> Total memory available in kernel for vmalloc allocations

It sparked my curiosity because it is a very high number and everywhere I searched it is exactly 34359738367 kB. It seems like an arbitrary maximum. But what is the significance of 34359738367 kB? It is not a multiple of 2, not a prime number, but it is 0x7FFFFFFFF in hexadecimal. I also noticed `pmap` process memory map addresses max out at 0x7FFFFFFFF. But then what is the practical significance of 0x7FFFFFFFF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s 32 TiB, the amount of space [set aside for `vmalloc` in the Linux kernel’s x86-64 memory map](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html).

It’s large because the 64-bit address space is large. I don’t think there’s any significance to its specific size other than it was a neat subdivision when the layout was designed.